# Rails 3 Should require_tree be used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

The [asset_pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)  mentions the use of `require_tree` for JavaScript and style-sheet files to recursively load every file of the respective files types, but doesn't mention any advantages or disadvantages of doing so. For instance are there any benefits to me having `require_tree` in my application.js file? In one case it prevents me from manually having to include individual javascript files for various pages. On the other hand theres been many occasions where I forget that I'm using the `require_tree` directive and accidentally loading libraries more than once.

Are there any performance-related issues involved in loading javascript/stylesheet files for pages that don't even make use of them (as would be the case in using `require_tree`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using require_tree, there is absolutely no reason to manually require your own files. You shouldn't do so, but it won't hurt if you do since Rails is smart enough to not require the same file twice.

However, you should require files that are "vendorized" or in a gem. "require_tree" won't require those files automatically. It only requires files that are in app/assets/{type}.

Comment: Not sure what version of Rails you're using that is smart enough to determine that a Javascript library has already been loaded but 3.1.3 certainly doesn't :/

Comment: I just checked in 3.2.3 and I confirm that files are not required twice. Rails is smart enough to figure out that you already manually required the file when parsing a directory with require_tree.